# How to overcome invalid identifier Error?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a table but its throwing error like invalid identifier in where condition `where REGION='Asia Pacific (Mumbai)'`.

Create table statement:

```
create or replace table PrimaryDB.sch.tableB as
  select CUSTOMERID, USER_ORDER_COUNT, TOTAL_SPENT, TAGS
  from SourceDB.sch.tableA
  where REGION = 'Asia Pacific(Mumbai)';
```

Compilation error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 134 invalid identifier
> 'REGION'

Comment: have you tried it using alias name for the table ?

Comment: no i havent tried

Comment: Do you actually have a column called `REGION` on the table? Posting the table definition would help.

Comment: Are you sure REGION column exists? Or have you mispelled the column name ? Just to make sure , run this sql command to check the columns and ensure the column exists - DESCRIBE SourceDB.sch.tableA;

Comment: When you will be checking the column existence ensure its name displayed in all capital letters, otherwise use its name in your query surrounded by double-quotes in exact case as you see it using the ```DESCRIBE```command.